# JNLP API to retrieve the j2se element(s)

Tags: java, api, jnlp

Is there a way to *programatically* find the j2se value(s) in the jnlp file, from within an extension installer (java code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, so long as you can determine the URL of the JNLP. A JNLP is just XML, so can be parsed by the J2SE XML APIs.

..I thought Sun introduced a method to provide the URL, but I cannot recall what it is right now. One way to work it if I remember incorrectly, is to write a property in the main JNLP as to the URL, then take it from there.